# How to take a function as an input in Ti Nspire Basic?

Tags: ti-basic, ti-nspire

I am trying to write a program for calculating the instantenious voltage of an inductor. I want to take the function of current (a function of t). I am also trying to run this on Ti-nspire CX instead of CAS if it matters

I first tried this.

```
Define LibPub indvoltage()=
Prgm
:Request "Inductance", L
:RequestStr "Current Function (I(t))",it
:Request "Time (t)",time
:Local derresult,result
:derresult:=nDeriv(it,t,time)
:result:=l*derresult
:Disp "Instantenious Voltage = ",resultres
:Disp res
:EndPrgm
```

This doesn't work, then I staered using expr, which didnt work either.

```
Define LibPub indvoltage()=
Prgm
:Request "Inductance", L
:RequestStr "Current Function (I(t))",it
:Request "Time (t)",time
:Local derresult,result
:expr(it)->it
:derresult:=nDeriv(it,t,time)
:result:=l*derresult
:Disp "Instantenious Voltage = ",resultres
:Disp res
:EndPrgm
```

expr doesn't work because it directly tried to evaluate the inside. I then tried

```
Define LibPub indvoltage()=
Prgm
:Request "Inductance (L)",l
:RequestStr "Current Function (I(t))",it
:Request "Time (t)",time
:Local res
:"nDeriv("&it&",t,time)"→res
:expr(res)→res
:res:= res * l
:Disp res
:EndPrgm
```

now it is raising an error when I try to run it. I am at my wits end. Please help

Comment: no way to do it without CAS

Answer (score 0):

**You simply cannot.** If you are interested in writing complex programs (this classifies as a complex program), you should look into writing them in Lua. You can't start writing a Lua program on your calculator directly, but you can use the (rather limited) Lua IDE of the Student Software on your PC. You can also install an on-calc IDE (I'd recommend Jens' Lua IDE).

Also, if I remember correctly, in one of the latest updates they added support for python. If you are more familiar with python, go for it. But I am not so sure it will integrate very well with the CAS server, so you may not have access to all the cool maths features. (Also its *way* slower than Lua, and doesn't have as many features, but you don't appear to need them anyway).